# "to have something being done" or "to be having something done"

Tags: grammar, causative-have

Which one is grammatically correct?

- They have their wedding cake being made.
- They are having their wedding cake made.

Comment: They are both grammatical, although the second might be more common.

Answer (score -2):

The OP has posted:
1) They have their wedding cake being made.
2) They are having their wedding cake made.

Sentence 1) is not grammatical.

Sentence 2) is grammatical: to have something done

Aka: They're having their wedding cake made.

Comment: *They have their child being tutored in math at ABC123 Tutoring.*

Comment: I didn't write **having** but **have**, nor did the OP.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Ok to very clear. You wrote: They ***have their child being tutored*** in math at ABC 123 Tutoring. So, I wrote: ***That is dodgy***. It should be: ***They are having their child tutored in math at ABC 123 Tutoring***.  Now, that should be clear. I meant to write: "Not: have x being tutored". That is not grammatical in English at all. "He has his dog being washed at the pet store?" I don't think so....

Comment: If what is referred to is a general practice or something  done on a regular basis, I would consider the pattern with **have** grammatical.  If not a general practice or regular thing, I would consider the usage marginal.

Comment: **have it being brought** https://books.google.com/books?id=fKL_HCz5m1QC&pg=PA221&dq=%22have+it+being%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQ65Tu88LeAhWtneAKHUk_CVAQ6AEIRTAF#v=onepage&q=%22have%20it%20being%22&f=false

Comment: **have it being tested** https://books.google.com/books?id=WNjUAAAAMAAJ&q=%22have+it+being%22&dq=%22have+it+being%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwoI-49MLeAhXMVN8KHZm2BKEQ6AEILjAB

Comment: **have it being disrupted** https://books.google.com/books?id=RPc0AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA9&dq=%22have+it+being%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwoI-49MLeAhXMVN8KHZm2BKEQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22have%20it%20being%22&f=false

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Those are not:  ***They have their child being tutored in math at ABC123 Tutoring.*** Why are you not recognizing what you wrote and trying to change it into something else?

Comment: I'm showing you a passive pattern with **have** + {object} + **being** + {past participle}  It's an alternative to **having** + {object} + **be** + {past participle}

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo No, you are doing everything to make it sound like what I said about your comment under my answer is not correct. It is correct and your sentence is not grammatical as written.